# How to reach to the child of a game object using FindGameObjectWithTag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the hierarchy, I have a parent Game Object (named "parent"), which has a child (named "child" and tagged "John"). Initially, The parent is active but the child is inactive.

The parent has a script component, in the Update() function of which I have:

```
GameObject go = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("John");
go.SetActive(true);
```

It doesn't work and I get "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" in the console. Even if the child is initially activated and I want to deactivate it, it still doesn't work and I get the same error. Why? And is it a good idea to use `FindGameObjectWithTag()` in Update() in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

In Unity, you can't get an inactive GameObject using any Find function unfortunately.
If you're not creating your GameObject go dynamically, use a public variable and assign it via inspector, it's way better performance wise (as Unity probably uses references), and it's easier (imagine you change a tag, you won't need to check in all your code references to that tag)

Comment: Side note: You don't need the editor reference if you want to keep the "findTag" style, you only need to declare the variable of the object at the begining and find it on awake (remember to set it active initially), on the awake find it by tag, and store it in a variable, then you can use this reference to activate and deactivate it.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Jichael, you cannot use Find functions to get inactive gameobjects.
You can however use:

```
var yourComponent = GetComponentInChildren<YourComponentType>(true);
```

If your child object has any component attached to it, you could easilly get it like this. Note the `true` (boolean) parameter. This is used to indicate that you want to check for inactive gameobjects.

A more detailed example:

```
var spriteRenderer = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>(true);
spriteRenderer.Sprite = yourSpriteVariable;
spriteRenderer.gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

This is also better performant than using Find functionality, since you only need to look through the child objects of the calling behaviour.